# MYSQL sort result by number of occurrences

Tags: mysql

I have a db like this

```
ID    DESCRIPTION
1     potato tomato
2     potato
3     salad coffee
4     potato salad
5     coffee
```

If I made a search of words "potato" and "salad", result must be

```
ID    RESULT
4     2
3     1
2     1
1     1
```

I have made this in php, but with many query depending on number of words to search and I think this is not good...

Is possible to make this only in mysql?

Comment: To do **what** exactly?

Comment: I need my table ordered in that way... I want to know witch id have more words from those I've been looking for

P.S. sorry for my english...

Comment: See REPLACE()..

Comment: You have a poor DB design for doing that kind of sort. When you decide not to normalize your data, you end up fighting to do what should be simple tasks as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  ID int,
  DESCRIPTION varchar(20)
);

INSERT products (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES
(1,'potato tomato'),
(2,'potato'),
(3,'salad coffee'),
(4,'potato salad'),
(5,'coffee');

SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.DESCRIPTION,
    COUNT(w.word) word_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(w.word) words
FROM products p
JOIN
    (
        SELECT 'potato' word
        UNION ALL SELECT 'salad'
    ) w
ON p.DESCRIPTION LIKE CONCAT('%',w.word,'%')
GROUP BY p.ID,p.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY word_count DESC
```